# Show that a Series Converges using Induction and MCT.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, induction

Question: Show that the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$ converges as follows. Let Sn denote the nth partial sums. Show that S2n−1 is a bounded monotone sequence and therefore convergent. Then show that Sn actually converges by noting that the difference between S2n and S2n−1 is small.

Let an = $\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$, Sn = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ an

a1 = -1 --------------------- a2 = 1/2

a3 = -1/3 ------------------ a4 = 1/4

a5 = -1/5 ------------------ a6 = 1/6

```
  .                    .

  .                    .

  .                    .
```

S2n-1 = $\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ a2n-1

S1 = -1

S2 = -1/3

S3 = -1/5

Claim: S2n-1 is monotone increasing

S1 < S2

S2 < S3

Prove using induction:

Let P(n): S2n-1 < S2n

P(1): S1 < S2 : -1 < -1/3 (True)

P(2): S3 < S4 : -1/5 < -1/7 (True)

This is what I have got so far, can anyone help me out because I'm lost, the induction is confusing for me, thank you very much.

Comment: Hi. Can you check and confirm that you understand what a [partial sum](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-bc/bc-series-new/bc-10-1/v/partial-sum-notation) is?

Answer (score 1):

The series converges according to the Leibniz's alternating series test. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test .

The OP's method also works as follows:
\begin{align}
b_n&=S_{2n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(-\frac1{2k-1}+\frac1{2k}\right)=b_{n-1}-\frac1{(2n-1)2n}<b_{n-1}\\
b_n&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{-1}{(2k-1)2k}>\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{-1}{(2k-1)^2}>-1-\sum_{k=2}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k-2)^2}=-1-\frac14\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{k^2}\\
&>-1-\frac{\pi^2}{24}\\\\
\text{So }b_n&\text{ is decreasing but lower bounded. Similarly,}\\\\
c_n&=S_{2n+1}=-1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\frac1{2k}-\frac1{2k+1}\right)=c_{n-1}+\frac1{2n(2n+1)}>b_{n-1}\\
c_n&=-1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{2k(2k+1)}<-1+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(2k)^2}=-1+\frac14\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k^2}<-1+\frac{\pi^2}{24}\\\\
\text{So }c_n&\text{ is increasing but upper bounded.}\\\\
\end{align}
Therefore, both $S_{2n}$ and $S_{2n+1}$ converges. And as both of those converge,
\begin{align}
0&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(S_{2n}-S_{2n+1}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n}-\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n+1}\\
\therefore&\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}S_{2n+1}
\end{align}
So $S_n$ converges.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering the question! But I don't know how you got your S2n? because what I got for my induction so far is, Assume P(K) : S2n-1 = $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1}{2k-1}$ is true. Consider P(K+1) : S2n = $\sum_{k=1}^n+1 \frac{(-1}{2k-1}$ = S2n = $[\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-1}{2k-1}][\frac{(-1}{2n}]$